# How to replace goroutines loop by channels in Go

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I have a loop, for each iteration I have a new channel source, that I should handle. Ok, it's better to show my code. I have list of files, each file I want to tail (like tail -f). I am using `github.com/ActiveState/tail` package.

```
for _, tailFile := range files {
    t, _ := tail.TailFile(tailFile, c)

    // Goroutine per tailing file
    go func() {
        for line := range t.Lines { // t.Lines is a channel
            // Do some magic here
        }
    }()
}
```

I can have thousands of files and I want to run my tail in parallel. As you see my program will have thousands of goroutines. Can this loop be changed to channels, with only 1 goroutine?

Comment: goroutines are cheap, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, the answer can be "goroutines are good for this case". Well explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find a similar approach (one goroutine per file) in the blog post [pipelines](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines).

> The MD5All implementation in [`parallel.go`](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines/parallel.go) starts a new goroutine for each file. **In a directory with many large files, this may allocate more memory than is available on the machine.**
>
> We can limit these allocations by bounding the number of files read in parallel. In [`bounded.go`](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines/bounded.go), we do this by creating a fixed number of goroutines for reading files.
> Our pipeline now has three stages: walk the tree, read and digest the files, and collect the digests.

You could organize your own code to use a limited number of goroutines, if you find yourself limited by memory allocated by a too large number of goroutines. (the goroutine itself is cheap, but the memory allocated for the "magic" part can be big)

Comment: @plutov.by that would help indeed (http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs): if the memory remains stable, you don't need to limit the goroutines.